# Matplotlib cannot plot points on basemap from CSV, but plots corectly from JSON

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

**Problem**

I'm trying to plot a set of points on a base-map. Below is my code. However it doesn't display it correctly where it supposed to be displaying it on the map.  I have added below a Dropbox link to the csv file I am using.

[Dropbox link to the csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ptyg3q2gy9i3yb1/AACuu3A9Yn8Y-Be9GIaSje78a?dl=0)

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#read data from CSV 
building = pd.read_csv('masteronlyfive.csv')

# convert coords to float type
building = building.astype({"lat": float, "long": float})

# convert to geodata series
building = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(towers, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(building.lat,building.long))

# set CRS
building.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
building.head()

# read basemap file and set CRS
world = geopandas.read_file("South_Africa_Polygon.shp")
world.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}

# Plot basemap
ax = world.plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')

# plot points
building.plot(ax=ax, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: This how it looks with the code, which is incorrect.]

**What I have tried**

I have taken the co-ordinates and re-coded them in a json format, instead of csv, so Im reading the data from a json array rather than doing a csv import, as such below and they work completely fine, its totally shocking for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#reading from json array
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Country': ['building', 'building', 'building', 'building', 'building'],
     'Latitude': [-28.506806, -27.463611, -29.192053, -28.871950, -27.242444],
     'Longitude': [28.613972, 28.040001, 26.235583,27.873739, 28.838861]})

#creating geopandas points from the coordinates
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))


#reading the basemap file
world = geopandas.read_file("South_Africa_Polygon.shp")

# plotting the basemap 
ax = world.plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')

# plotting the geodata points
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: This how it looks - which is correct, when it reads from the JSON data import]

What could I possibly be doing wrong that the exact same co-ords works fine from JSON but not from CSV.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a geodataframe, change long/lat order, like below:

```
# convert to geodata series
building = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(building.long, building.lat)
)
```

Your longitude is x, not y. Your latitude is y. Hence when dealing with the `points_from_xy()` function, longitude (which is `x`) comes first. This is a very common error and you can spot it in the plot – the polygon boundaries are diagonally opposite to your points cluster, so it is most often the order of lat/lon!

P.S. I am not sure why your original code references `towers` variable in that code snippet, so I removed it.